# String manipulation in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to do string manipulation in perl like so.

```
/q1.pl asad566sads asad575sads
```

then this prints

```
asad566sads 
asad567sads
asad568sads
...
...
asad575sads
```

I am thinking somehow separate the string, then join it back up again?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


if (@ARGV != 2){
    print "error\n";
}else{
    my $numb1 = $ARGV[0];
    my $numb2 = $ARGV[1];

    $numb1 =~ s/(\d*)\D/$1/g;
    $numb2 =~ s/(\d*)\D/$1/g;


    print "$numb1 \n";
    print "$numb2 \n";


    for ($i=$numb1; $i<$numb2; $i++){

        #my $numb_2_print;
    my $string_to_print = $ARGV[0];

    $string_to_print =~ s/(\D*)\d(\D*)/$1$i$2/g;
    print "$string_to_print\n";
    }
}
```

EDIT: assume numbers on appear once in string for this question. sorry about that

Comment: Is `a1a1 a2a2` allowed? What should the result be?

Comment: for this question no. Can assume numbers only come once.

Comment: will they always have the same beginning and end?

Comment: yes the string around it will remain same. only the numbers change.

Comment: *shrug* Supported a1a1..a2a2 anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Invalid number of parameters" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($pref1, $num1, $suf1) = $ARGV[0] =~ /^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$/ or die "Invalid Parameter";
my ($pref2, $num2, $suf2) = $ARGV[1] =~ /^(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)$/ or die "Invalid Parameter";

die "Prefixes don't match" if ($pref1 ne $pref2);
die "Suffixes don't match" if ($suf1 ne $suf2);

print "$pref1$_$suf1\n" for ($num1..$num2);
```

Addendum: If you care about the numbers being the same length, you can use this printf statement instead

```
printf "%s%0" . length($num2) . "d%s\n", $pref1, $_, $suf1 for ($num1..$num2);
```

Comment: Added an alternative print statement in case you care about the numbers being 0 padded so they're the same length.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $s = 'a1a1';
my $e = 'a2a2';

my @s_parts = $s =~ /(\d+|\D+)/g;
my @e_parts = $e =~ /(\d+|\D+)/g;

die if @s_parts != @e_parts;

my @loops;
for my $i (0..$#s_parts) {
    if ($s_parts[$i] =~ /^\d/) {
       die if $s_parts[$i] > $e_parts[$i];
       push @loops, [ $s_parts[$i] .. $e_parts[$i] ];
    } else {
       die if $s_parts[$i] ne $e_parts[$i];
       push @loops, [ $s_parts[$i] ];
    }
}

NestedLoops(\@loops, sub {
   print(@_, "\n");
});
```

```
a1a1
a1a2
a2a1
a2a2
```

Answer (score 1):

The range operator is your friend (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($start, $end) = @ARGV;
$start =~ s/([a-zA-Z]+)$//;
$end   =~ s/([a-zA-Z]+)$//;
my $trailing = $1;

foreach ( $start..$end ) {
   print "$_$trailing\n";
}

__END__
asad566sads
asad567sads
asad568sads
asad569sads
asad570sads
asad571sads
asad572sads
asad573sads
asad574sads
asad575sads
```